# Nested mapping using RKObjectMapping

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, restkit

I'm trying to perform an object mapping using RKObjectMapping.

Here is a sample of my JSON:

```
{
        "notification": {
            "created_at": "2012-10-23T02:43:43-04:00",
            "delivered": true,
            "id": 3915,
            "missed": false,
            "rejected": false,
            "search_request_id": 360,
            "bid": {
                "bid_type": "none",
                "bid_type_values": null,
                "comment": "hi\n",
                "created_at": "2012-10-23T02:43:54-04:00",
                "delivered": true,
                "delivery_type": "email",
                "id": 268,
                        "has_chat_session": true,
            },
            "search_request": {
                "created_at": "2012-10-23T02:43:42-04:00",
                "customer_id": 6,
                "id": 360,
                "latitude": "40.7536854",
                "location": "10001",
                "longitude": "-73.9991637",
            }
        }
```

I have verified the JSON using jsonlint and it is valid.

Here is my mapping.

```
    RKObjectMapping *bidMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Bid class]]; 
    [bidMapping mapKeyPath:@"comment" toAttribute:@"comment"];
    [bidMapping mapKeyPath:@"chat_session_id" toAttribute:@"chatSessionId"];
    [objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:bidMapping forKeyPath:@"bid"];

    RKObjectMapping *searchRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SearchRequest class]];
    [searchRequestMapping mapKeyPath:@"purpose" toAttribute:@"purpose"];
    [searchRequestMapping mapKeyPath:@"customer_Id" toAttribute:@"customerId"];
    [searchRequestMapping mapKeyPath:@"need" toAttribute:@"need"];
    [objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:searchRequestMapping forKeyPath:@"search_request"];

    RKObjectMapping *notificationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Notification class]];  // have not mapped all the attributes.
    [notificationMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute: @"notificationId"];
    [notificationMapping mapKeyPath:@"created_at" toAttribute:@"timestamp"];
    [notificationMapping mapKeyPath:@"vendor_id" toAttribute:@"vendorId"];
    [notificationMapping mapKeyPath:@"bid" toRelationship:@"bid" withMapping:bidMapping];
    [notificationMapping mapKeyPath:@"search_request" toRelationship:@"search_request" withMapping:notificationMapping]; 
    [objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:notificationMapping forKeyPath:@"notification"];
```

The program is crashing with an Assertion failure that i am not able to debug when i try to loadObjectsAtResourcePath. I tried using rootKeyPaths as well but to no avail.

Can someone help me find the error please?

thank you!

ps: I want to add a NSDictionary parameter and the documentation says use appendQueryParams:params. But i get a warning saying it is deprecated. Any alternatives i could use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given wrong mapping here-

```
    [notificationMapping mapKeyPath:@"search_request" toRelationship:@"search_request" withMapping:notificationMapping];
```

You chould give searchRequestMapping like-

```
    [notificationMapping mapKeyPath:@"search_request" toRelationship:@"search_request" withMapping:searchRequestMapping];
```

Instead of appendQueryParams:params, you can use method following method of RKClient-

```
- (RKRequest *)get:(NSString *)resourcePath queryParameters:(NSDictionary *)queryParameters delegate:(NSObject<RKRequestDelegate> *)delegate;
```

Comment: facepalm. Really silly error on my part. Thanks for spotting it Rahul. Cheers!

Comment: the answer is outdated

Comment: Hi Alberto, Could you update/post your answer here? I have stopped working on iOS few years back so I am not aware of the recent changes.